# Pass a bytes32 as argument in Remix

Tags: solidity

This is my smart contract:

```
contract Bank {
  mapping(bytes32 => State) internal states;
  bytes32[] internal possibleStates;

  struct State {
    // a boolean to check if the state is actually created
    bool hasBeenCreated;
    // a mapping of functions that can be executed when in this state
    mapping(bytes4 => bool) allowedFunctions;
    // a list of all the roles that have been configured for this state
    bytes32[] allowedRoles;
    // a list of all the preconditions that have been configured for this state
    function(bytes32, bytes32) internal view[] preConditions;
    // a list of callbacks to execute before the state transition completes
    function(bytes32, bytes32) internal[] callbacks;
    // a list of states that can be transitioned to
    bytes32[] nextStates;
    // function that executes logic and then does a StateTransition
    bytes4 preFunction;
  }

 
  function createState(bytes32 stateName) public {
    states[stateName].hasBeenCreated = true;
  }
}
```

But when I try to use the function createStake in Remix with the following values:
"test" or "test, test" or ["test"] or ["test", "test"]

Nothing works I always have the following error message: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="test, test", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.4.0)

Can someone explain me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text has to be in hexadecimal and occupy 64 hex characters. To convert "test" you can type in the remix console

```
> web3.utils.padLeft(web3.utils.asciiToHex("test"), 64)

0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000686f6c61
```

Then you can type `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000686f6c61` as parameter when calling function `createState`.

Answer (score 1):

Ismael's answer is the best

I've made an online tool to do the same

- https://eth-tools.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/stringToHex.html
- https://eth-tools.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/hexToString.html